# Can Android app on ChromeOS create a KeyPair that is at least SECURITY_LEVEL_TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, key-pair, androidappsonchromeos, trusted-computing

I'm trying to find out if creating hardware backed secure keys are possible inside an Android app running on a Chromebook. I'm asking because to my knowledge, all Android apps on ChromeOS runs on some kind of virtualised environment and might not have access to certain host OS features.

Specifically my use case would be using the `java.security.KeyPairGenerator` to create a `KeyPair` that is at stored on the secure chip inside the Chromebook and not software backed.

Comment: Also stumbled across this issue, did you find an answer to your question Khongor?